# How to get count of words in Power BI if the words are separated by commas in a column?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have an excel file and have loaded it on Power BI and I need to get the count of number of occurrences that a word appears in a particular column. In my case the column is ProductError

For example

ProductNameError

1. Apple, Orange, Mango
2. Apple, Banana, Mango
3. Kiwi, Apple, Pineapple, Strawberry

I need to create a visual (table) on Power BI where it defines the occurrences as

ProductNameError   Count

1. Apples.            3
2. Mango.             2
3. Orange             1
4. Banana             1
5. Kiwi               1
6. Pineapple          1
7. Strawberry         1

I tried using DAX measures and also creating Python scripts in Power BI, but, nothing works

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy to accomplish via Power Query.

- Split column by delimiter into **rows**
- Trim leading/trailing whitepace
- Group by

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WciwoyEnVUfAvSsxLB9K+QCpfKVYHLuGUmAeEyBLemeWZOgpQ6YDMvNRECDO4pCixPCm1qKhSKTYWAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ProductNameError = _t]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"ProductNameError", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "ProductNameError"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ProductNameError", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"ProductNameError"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?